# CKEditor : Defining Configuration in Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a ASP.net user control with the below CKEditor

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtHtmlText" BasePath="~/Scripts/ckeditor/" 
        Toolbar="Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|Subscript|Superscript|-    |TextColor|BGColor|Font|FontSize
JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|Justify|-|Outdent|Indent|-    |NumberedList|BulletedList
Cut|Copy|Paste|PasteText|PasteFromWord|-|HorizontalRule|Link|Unlink|-    |Source|About"runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

I'm trying to override word count limit defined in config.js of CKEditor. I used the below code int the .ascx file and is getting the Error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined". Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.replace('txtHtmlText',
{
    wordcount: {
        // Whether or not you want to show the Paragraphs Count
        showParagraphs: false,

        // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
        showWordCount: false,

        // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
        showCharCount: true,

        // Whether or not you want to count Spaces as Chars
        countSpacesAsChars: false,

        // Whether or not to include Html chars in the Char Count
        countHTML: false,

        // Maximum allowed Word Count, -1 is default for unlimited
        maxWordCount: 500,

        // Maximum allowed Char Count, -1 is default for unlimited
        maxCharCount: 500
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried today for my requirement and I was able to successfully add the feature.

If I would have been in your place, I would have checked couple of things

1. Is the reference to CKEditor is added (I know its obvious)
2. Add extraPlugins : 'wordcount', just above wordcount: {
3. Check developer console for any further investigation.

This link helped me solve my problem @ https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin/blob/master/wordcount/samples/wordcountWithMaxCount.html

Answer (score 0):

@Vinayak Prabha,

Try as suggested by Vikram. However a question ?

CKEditor ID "txtHtmlText" is server id, if you have to use in java script you should use client Id.

Try like this

> var ckEditorClientID = "#<%=txtHtmlText.ClientID %>";
>
> CKEDITOR.replace(ckEditorClientID,